# AWS S3 File Upload: S3Client Class Not Found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a large `functions.php` file which contains all the functions I'm using in my application.  At the top of it I include the `use Aws\S3\S3Client;` namespace.  Below the only contents to the file are a large list of functions.

I have one function called `uploadFile` which originally just loaded the file to the local disk and insert a record into a database.  Now I want to upload the file to the AWS S3 bucket, but when I try to use the AWS code I found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html

It gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found in C:\wamp\www\project\functions.php
```

Here is my local implementation:

```
function uploadFile($file_name, $target_directory, $files = null) {
    $bucket = getS3Bucket();
    $keyname = getS3Key();
    // $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk
    $filepath = $file_name;

    // Instantiate the client.
    $s3 = S3Client::factory();

    // Upload a file.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'       => $bucket,
        'Key'          => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $file_name,
        'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
        'ACL'          => 'public-read',
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
        'Metadata'     => array(
            'param1' => 'value 1',
            'param2' => 'value 2'
        )
    ));

    return $result;
}
```

It seems like I'm facing a problem of using the S3 API along with my procedural code.  Is there a way to handle this without having to re-write ALL the places where I do file uploads?  (In other words, I'll make any changes needed to the `uploadFile` function, but I'd hate to have to rewrite every implementation of that function.)

Comment: How did you install the SDK? Does your functions.php include something to setup autoloading for the SDK (e.g., `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`)?

Comment: I have a directory in the root called `thirdparty` and within that the `aws` SDK.  Stupidly I did NOT make any connection to it, though I don't see a `vendor/autoload.php` within it (though I will be looking into that right now).

Comment: That fixed that problem!  Now to figure out why it won't authenticate me.  Thanks Jeremy Lindblom!  If you submit as an awesome I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that you are not including anything in your `functions.php` to enable autoloading the SDK classes. What you include will depend on how you installed the SDK. If you used Composer, the autoloader to use would be located in `<your-project-root>/vendor/autoload.php`. You can look at the [SDK's Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html) for details on what to do for other installation methods (e.g., `aws.phar`  and `aws.zip`).